# Bring ASCII art to the 3rd dimension

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

In this challenge, You have to bring ASCII art (which are usually 2D) to 3D!

## How?

like this,

```
X X DD 
 X  D D
X X DD
```

to...

```
  X X DD 
 X X DD D
X X DDDD 
 X XDDD
X X DD
```

## Then How do we do *that*?

Given the ascii art and `N`, repeat this `N` times.

- for every character (we will call this `A`):
- let `B` be the character which is exactly 1 right and 1 up from `A`
- if `B` is a space or is undefined:
- set `B` to `A`.

## Specs

- The first input can be a string with newline characters or a list of strings representing the 2D ASCII art.
- You are allowed to use `%END%` to tag the end of input, but this is not required.
- The second input will be `N`. It will be a positive integer.
- all the lines of the strings will be the same length.

## Examples

Input: `("###\n###",1)`

Output:

```
 ###
####
###
```

## Rules

Basic [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

also, If you have questions, be sure to ask in the comments!

Comment: You might want to clarify that "blank" refers to space (U+0020) or nothing.

Comment: @LeakyNun Is it fixed now?

Comment: Is extra whitespaces allowed?

Comment: Yes, Those are allowed.

Comment: I think there should be a whole in the top right corner of your `D`. the bottom left `D` can't reach all the way up there.

Comment: @MartinEnder My program confirms that.

Comment: Can I assume that the length of each line will be the same? (Can I pre-pad the input with spaces on the right?)

Comment: @MartinEnder mine confirms your finding as well.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your question. Feel free to revert any edit.

Comment: Can I take the second input one higher?

Comment: Can the input be a 2D array in the sense of a char matrix? Rows right-padded with spaces so they all have the same length

Comment: Some of the answers here print ANSI escape sequences to move a terminal cursor around. This is allowed by consensus, but it might not be the kind of approach you intended, so I feel like it’s worth chiming in on.

Comment: @Lynn Well, that is one of the approach that I thought of.

Comment: Will the thing only have printable characters (and newlines)?

Comment: Yes, otherwise, we can't input it, I guess?

Comment: Again, can the input be a 2D array of chars (matrix of chars)? Please clarify :-)

Answer (score 18):

### Perl, 81 bytes

**75 bytes code + 6 for `-i -n0`.

Note that the `\e` characters are ASCII `\x1b` but `\e` is used for ease of testing.**

Please note that this solution uses ANSI escape sequences and requires a compatible terminal, as well as using the `-i` commandline argument to pass in the number of 'dimensions' you'd like.

```pl
$n=s/^//mg-1;s/ /\e[1C/g;print(s/^/\e[${^I}C/grm."\e[${n}A"),--$^I for($_)x$^I
```

#### Usage:

In a Linux compatible terminal, run `PS1=` first to ensure your prompt doesn't overwrite the displayed image.

```sh
perl -i10 -n0e '$n=s/^//mg-1;s/ /\e[1C/g;print(s/^/\e[${^I}C/grm."\e[${n}A"),--$^I for($_)x$^I' <<< ' 
ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL
         _^___
 L    __/   [] \    
LOL===__        \ 
 L      \________]
         I   I
        --------/
'

          ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL
         ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL
        ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL
       ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL\
      ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL\_]
     ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL\_]
    ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL\_]/
   ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL\_]/
  ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL\_]/
 ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL\_]/
   LOL==___^___]_\_\_]/
  LOL==__/ \_[]_\_\_]/
 LOL===__ \______\_]/
  L      \________]/
          I---I---/
         --------/

perl -i3 -n0e '$n=s/^//mg-1;s/ /\e[1C/g;print(s/^/\e[${^I}C/grm."\e[${n}A"),--$^I for($_)x$^I' <<< 'X X DD
 X  D D
X X DD
'
   X X DD
  X X DD D
 X X DDDD
  X XDDD
 X X DD
```

Answer (score 8):

### CJam, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
{{' 1$f+La@+..{sS@er}}*}
```

An unnamed block that expects a list of strings and the number of repetitions on the stack and leaves a new list of strings instead.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%202%0A%0A%7B%7B'%201%24f%2BLa%40%2B..%7BsS%40er%7D%7D*%7D%0A%0A~N*&input=X%20X%20DD%0A%20X%20%20D%20D%0AX%20X%20DD) (Includes a test wrapper that reads the string from STDIN for convenience.)

#### Explanation

```
{       e# Repeat this block N times...
  '     e#   Push a space character.
  1$    e#   Copy the current grid.
  f+    e#   Prepend the space to each line of the grid.
  La    e#   Push [[]].
  @+    e#   Pull up the other copy of the grid and prepend the [].
        e#   We've now got two copies of the grid, one shifted right by
        e#   a cell and one shifted down by a cell. We now want to replace
        e#   spaces in the latter with the corresponding character in the
        e#   former.
  ..{   e#   For each pair of characters in corresponding positions...
    s   e#     Turn the character in the down-shifted grid into a string.
    S   e#     Push " ".
    @   e#     Pull up the character from the right-shifted grid.
    er  e#     Replace spaces with that character.
  }
}*
```

Comment: Ten roflcopters! http://goo.gl/PEK4iB

Comment: Why doesn't `S` work for the initial space? Also, is it allowed to use variables (which might have been overwritten) in a function?

Comment: @LuisMendo `S` doesn't work, because then `f` would be mapping over that string instead. Re functions, I believe so, in "normal" languages, there are also many functions submissions that rely globals which aren't tampered with between invocations.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that a character in CJam is not the same as a one-character string

Comment: You can save one byte by using Convex as it has a one-char transliterate operator instead of a two-char: http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4vIDIKCnt7JyAxJGYrTGFAKy4ue3NTQMOLfX0qfQoKfk4q&input=WCBYIERECiBYICBEIEQKWCBYIERE (shameless plug)

Comment: @GamrCorps Thanks, I've posted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

### APL, 49 bytes

```
{⎕UCS 32⌈{s+(s=0)×1⊖¯1⌽s←0⍪⍵,0}⍣⍺⊣(32∘≠×⊣)⎕UCS↑⍵}
```

Input: vector of character vectors.
Example:

```
      2 {⎕UCS 32⌈{s+(s=0)×1⊖¯1⌽s←0⍪⍵,0}⍣⍺⊣(32∘≠×⊣)⎕UCS↑⍵} 'X X DD' ' X  D D' 'X X DD'
  X X DD 
 X X DD D
X X DDDD 
 X XDDD  
X X DD
```

How it works:

- `↑⍵` turns the argument into a matrix of chars
- `⎕UCS` from char to integer
- `(32∘≠×⊣)` substitute the spaces (32) with zeroes
- `...⍣⍺⊣` apply ⍺ (the left argument) times the function on the left
- `s←0⍪⍵,0` border with zeroes on top and on the right the argument
- `1⊖¯1⌽` rotate 1 up and 1 right
- `s+(s=0)×` sum to the original the shifted version but only on top of the zeroes of the original
- `32⌈` turns back the zeroes into 32s
- `⎕UCS` from integer to char

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 24 bytes

```
:"ct32>*TTYatFTEqYSy~*+c
```

Input format is

```
2
{'X X DD', ' X  D D', 'X X DD'}
```

So the other example is

```
1
{'###', '###'}
```

The output contains extra whitespace, which is allowed by the challenge.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiJjdDMyPipUVFlhdEZURXFZU3l-Kitj&input=Mgp7J1ggWCBERCcsICcgWCAgRCBEJywgJ1ggWCBERCd9)

---

If a 2D char array is acceptable as input (I've asked the OP twice...), the first `c` can be removed, so **23 bytes**:

```
:"t32>*TTYatFTEqYSy~*+c
```

Input format in this case is (all strings have equal lengths, which may require right-padding with spaces):

```
2
['X X DD '; ' X  D D'; 'X X DD ']
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiJ0MzI-KlRUWWF0RlRFcVlTeX4qK2M&input=MgpbJ1ggWCBERCAnOyAnIFggIEQgRCc7ICdYIFggREQgJ10)

---

#### Explanation

```
:        % Input number n implicitly. Generate [1 2 ... n]
"        % For loop: repeat n times
  c      %   Convert to char array. In the first iteration it inputs a cell array of
         %   strings implicitly and converts to a 2D char array, right-padding with
         %   spaces. In the next iterations it does nothing, as the top of the stack
         %   is already a 2D char array
  t32>*  %   Convert characters below 32 into 0
  TT     %   Push array [1 1]
  Ya     %   Pad the 2D char array with one zero in the two directions (up/down,
         %   left/right), on both sides
  t      %   Duplicate
  FTEq   %   Push array [-1 1]
  YS     %   Circularly shift the 2D char array one unit up and one unit right
  y      %   Push a copy of the non-shifted 2D array
  ~      %   Logical negate: nonzero entries become 0, zero entries become 1. This
         %   will be used as a mask for entries that need to be changed. Since the
         %   values at those entries are zero, we can simply add the new values. We do
         %   that by multiplying the mask by the shifted array and adding to the
         %   non-shifted array
  *      %   Multiply element-wise
  +      %   Add element-wise
  c      %   Convert the 2D array back to char
         % End for
         % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Convex](https://github.com/gamrcorps/convex), 23 bytes

Byte count assumes CP-1252 encoding.

```
{{' 1$f+La@+..{sS@Ë}}*}
```

An unnamed block that expects a list of strings and the number of repetitions on the stack and leaves a new list of strings instead.

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4vIDIKCnt7JyAxJGYrTGFAKy4ue3NTQMOLfX0qfQoKfk4q&input=WCBYIERECiBYICBEIEQKWCBYIERE)

This is a direct port of [my CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86302/8478) to Convex (which is heavily based on CJam). The only difference is that Convex uses `Ë` instead of `er` for transliteration, saving one byte. Thanks to GamrCorps for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>54</s> 33 bytes

```
ju+++dhG.bsmh|-d;;.t,Y+dNdtGGeG.*
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ju%2B%2B%2BdhG.bsmh%7C-d%3B%3B.t%2CY%2BdNdtGGeG.%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B2%2C%5B%22X+X+DD%22%2C%22+X++D+D%22%2C%22X+X+DD%22%5D%5D%0A%5B1%2C%5B%22%23%23%23%22%2C%22%23%23%23%22%5D%5D%0A%5B9%2C%5B%22+ROFL%3AROFL%3AROFL%3AROFL%22%2C%22+++++++++_%5E___%22%2C%22+L++++__%2F+++%5B%5D+%5C%5C++++%22%2C%22LOL%3D%3D%3D__++++++++%5C%5C+%22%2C%22+L++++++%5C%5C________%5D%22%2C%22+++++++++I+++I%22%2C%22++++++++--------%2F%22%5D%5D&debug=0)

Comment: why do you need two `;`?

Comment: @ven `;` is not the usual `;` in programming languages.

Comment: `;` is a variable.

Comment: ah pyth overloads `;` in lambdas...

Comment: @ven When you get along with Pyth, you would use `I`, `.?`, `V`, `F`, `;`, (explicit statements) very less, and they will be replaced by `?`, `m`, `u`, `F`, `M`, `L`, `R`, `#`, ...

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 95 bytes

```ruby
->a,n{n.downto(0){|i|f="<Esc>[1C"
$><<a.gsub(/^/,f*i).gsub(" ",f)+(i>0?"<Esc>[#{a.lines.size-1}A":"")}}
```

Each `<Esc>` is a literal ESC character (`0x1b`).

### Usage

Assign the lambda to a variable e.g. `func`.

```ruby
art = <<END
X X DD
 X  D D
X X DD
END

func[art, 2]
# Prints:
#   X X DD
#  X X DD D
# X X DDDD
#  X XDDD
# X X DD
```

### Ungolfed

```ruby
->(art, num) {
  num.downto(0) do |i|
    forward = "\e[1C"
    $> << art.gsub(/^/, forward * i).gsub(" ", forward) +
            (i > 0 ? "\e[#{art.lines.size - 1}A" : "")
  end
}
```

The `forward` escape sequence, `\e[1C`, moves the cursor forward (right) 1 space and `\e[<n>A` moves it up `n` lines. Basically what this code does is print the "layers" back to front, replacing spaces with the `forward` sequence to avoid overwriting the other layers with a space.

Comment: You accidentally put a `f=` before the `->` in the golfed version. Remove it for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 116 bytes

```
S=' '
def f(a,d):e=[S*len(`a`)];exec"a=[''.join(t[t[1]>S]for t in zip(S+x,y+S))for x,y in zip(a+e,e+a)];"*d;return a
```

I’ll golf this more soon.

Comment: Are you sure a `lambda` isn't shorter?

Comment: I need the assignment of `e` in there. Also, `exec` is a statement, so it can’t be in a lambda.

Comment: Ok. Just making sure.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 128 bytes

```
f=(a,n)=>n?f((a=[``,...a].map(s=>[...s||` `])).map((b,i)=>i--&&b.map((c,j)=>a[i][++j]>' '?0:a[i][j]=c))&&a.map(b=>b.join``),n-1):a
```

Accepts and returns an array of strings, prepends an extra row for the output, ensures each row contains at least a space, splits them all up into characters, loops though trying to copy the characters to the row above and column to the right, then recursively calls itself to complete the loop.